# Brute force with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, python-3.4

I am trying to brute force with `python selenium` But it seems to be too time taking unlike brute force with python requests,although both are different.I was wondering is there any way that brute force can be done more faster?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this for legitimate reasons...

Comment: Yes,obviously not for bad reasons,because I know the consequences

Comment: You're trying to brute force... what? A password entry field?

Comment: @James For password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once wrote a Python script that used Splinter to drive Firefox via Selenium for a video that demonstrated brute-forcing a Wordpress login in the same fashion (for educating site owners about how easy it was to brute-force the Wordpress login by default). I used this method precisely because it was slower (and it was possible to see it happening).

There's no getting away from the fast that it will be much faster using `requests`, because it still needs to load all the CSS, images and Javascript. Using a headless browser like PhantomJS might help since it won't have to render it on screen, but if you don't need to see it anyway you might as well use `requests`.

Comment: Yes but It is complicate parsing javascript using requests

Comment: Do you need to handle Javascript?

Comment: Yes,that was the reason I switched to selenium

Comment: Then PhantomJS is probably your best bet. I use [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this kind of stuff in Python because it's got a generic interface to things like Selenium, Chrome and PhantomJS, making it easier to switch. If you rewrite your script to use Splinter and then set it to use PhantomJS as the browser, it's likely you'll see a speed increate over a desktop browser, and as PhantomJS is Webkit-based it's not too dissimilar to Chrome or Safari.